# 80' ¼" RO WATER LINE FROM HOUSE TO GARAGE

Tags: water, flow-rate

Can I run a ¼" water line off my RO system 80' to  my garage and still  have decent fl

Comment: Decent flow for what?  Filling a glass of water okay, running a pressure washer no.

Answer (score 1):

For typical 1/4" OD plastic tubing with a 0.170" inside diameter, the friction head is 188 PSI for a 1 Gallon per minute flow rate, or a more reasonable (unclear if the RO system output goes that high, though) 27 PSI for 0.35 GPM, which most will find tediously slow.

1/4" ID plastic tubing would be 28.9 PSI at 1 GPM which might be marginally acceptable for most people's impatience at filling a glass.

Actual flow will depend on the pressure at the RO storage tank - when the tap is opened down the line whatever flow rate that makes the pressure at the tank equal to the friction head in the pipe (with no pressure at the far end) will flow. As the storage pressure varies, the flow rate will vary.

I used this handy calculator: http://irrigation.wsu.edu/Content/Calculators/General/Pipeline-Pressure-Loss.php

Dependiing on the actual garage use case putting 5 gallons in a jug and carrying it to the garage (put it in a water-cooler type dispenser) might be a better fit...

Comment: You could use 1/4" OD tubing and add a small RO-grade pressure tank in the garage. Make a T in the line for the tank and install it near the point of use if possible. It will take a while to fill the tank, but once the entire system comes to equilibrium, you'll get flow in the garage just as good as it is in the house, up until the tank is depleted.

Comment: The 188 psi part is just confusing to somebody without an understanding of fluid mechanics. Something like "1 GPM would require more than 188 psi of pressure" at least hints at how to interpret nonsense results from that calculator.

Comment: The friction head correlations with flow rates are also confusing. I expect that many casual readers will scan over the friction head part and then interpret the 27 psi and 28.9 psi values as minimum tank pressures instead of frictional losses. Technically friction head has units of distance, where "friction loss" is pedantically true and probably more intuitive. "Would be" -> "would lose" kills the passive voice and is more intuitive also.